# How to handle dictionary in JSON file to txt file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have sample.json file which includes code in the c lang dataset represented as a dictionary

```
{
  "0_0": 
"int curl_mvsprintf ( char * buffer , const char * format , va_list ap_save ) {\n int retcode ;\n retcode = dprintf_formatf ( & buffer , storebuffer , format , ap_save ) ;\n * buffer = 0 ;\n return retcode ;\n }",

  "0_1": 
"static int alloc_addbyter ( int output , FILE * data ) {\n struct asprintf * infop = ( struct asprintf * ) data ;\n unsigned char outc = ( unsigned char ) output ;\n if ( ! infop -> buffer ) {\n infop -> buffer = malloc ( 32 ) ;\n if ( ! infop -> buffer ) {\n infop -> fail = 1 ;\n return - 1 ;\n }\n infop -> alloc = 32 ;\n infop -> len = 0 ;\n }\n else if ( infop -> len + 1 >= infop -> alloc ) {\n char * newptr ;\n newptr = realloc ( infop -> buffer , infop -> alloc * 2 ) ;\n if ( ! newptr ) {\n infop -> fail = 1 ;\n return - 1 ;\n }\n infop -> buffer = newptr ;\n infop -> alloc *= 2 ;\n }\n infop -> buffer [ infop -> len ] = outc ;\n infop -> len ++ ;\n return outc ;\n }",  
}
```

and wanna process it either using panda or python to get the following text for the classification task in python the separator should be tab '\t' and save it in **sample.txt**
if filename end with (0) like 0_0  then put **lable1** (*_0)
else **lable2** like (0_1)or (*_1)

```
label1  int curl_mvsprintf ( char * buffer , const char * format , va_list ap_save ) {\n int retcode ;\n retcode = dprintf_formatf ( & buffer , storebuffer , format , ap_save ) ;\n * buffer = 0 ;\n return retcode ;\n }
lable2  static int alloc_addbyter ( int output , FILE * data ) {\n struct asprintf * infop = ( struct asprintf * ) data ;\n unsigned char outc = ( unsigned char ) output ;\n if ( ! infop -> buffer ) {\n infop -> buffer = malloc ( 32 ) ;\n if ( ! infop -> buffer ) {\n infop -> fail = 1 ;\n return - 1 ;\n }\n infop -> alloc = 32 ;\n infop -> len = 0 ;\n }\n else if ( infop -> len + 1 >= infop -> alloc ) {\n char * newptr ;\n newptr = realloc ( infop -> buffer , infop -> alloc * 2 ) ;\n if ( ! newptr ) {\n infop -> fail = 1 ;\n return - 1 ;\n }\n infop -> buffer = newptr ;\n infop -> alloc *= 2 ;\n }\n infop -> buffer [ infop -> len ] = outc ;\n infop -> len ++ ;\n return outc ;\n }
```

Expected output after read txt file using panda
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```py
import json

with open("sample.json", "r") as f:
    sample_dict = json.load(f)

output_str = ""

for key, val in sample_dict.items():
    if key.endswith("0"):
        output_str += "label1\t"
    else:
        output_str += "label2\t"
    
    output_str += val + "\n"

with open("sample.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(output_str)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.txt")
```

NOTE: you can go directly from json to pandas:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open("sample.json", "r") as f:
    sample_dict = json.load(f)

df_dict = {"label": [], "text": []}
for key, val in sample_dict.items():
    if key.endswith("0"):
        df_dict["label"].append("label1")
    else:
        df_dict["label"].append("label2") 
    df_dict["text"].append(val)        

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
df
```

Comment: this is what I got  multiple lines https://github.com/Mohammed20201991/DataSets/blob/main/NLP_data/sample.txt where I need the resulting file like https://github.com/Mohammed20201991/DataSets/blob/main/NLP_data/sample1.txt

Comment: It looks like the `\n` that occur in the input get parse as newlines. If I understand correctly, you want to prevent that from happening, right?

Comment: @دايخفيزمنبايخ Wait, in your new expected output, all the `\n` just disappear? Is that what's supposed to happen? It's not what you showed in the question.

Comment: the \n should be included in code (wich I need the code that we read from dictionary save as it is including '\n')

Comment: In any case, I think you can get what you want by changing @AlexL's code to do `output_str += val.replace("\n", r"\n") + "\n"`. The `r` before my double quotes in the replacement string will keep that `\n` as their literal two character string instead of interpreting it as a newline character.

Comment: now yes it works as I want thanks as I did update for Alex L  thanks for all of you joanis

Comment: note you can also go directly from json to pandas df, see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks @AlexL that is really good enhancement so In this case I will avoid  memory limitation when loading from text